# Twig RAW filter on literal string not working

Tags: twig

`{{ (vendorData.description) ? vendorData.description : "<em>No Description Entered</em>"|raw }}`

When the value is not present I see: 
`<em>No Description Entered</em>`
Printed literally on the screen in the web browser.

Raw should force the characters to be literal, not `&gt; &lt;` etc.

Why does this not work on a "created string" but if I do it on a string variable it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place brackets around the whole statement like so:

```
{{ ((vendorData)
    ? vendorData
    : "<em>No Description Entered</em>")|raw }}
```

Here is a working twigfiddle to show it working:
https://twigfiddle.com/fs2oc2

You can use twigfiddle to experiment with your code.

---

From feedback in comments section:

here is a twig example to show what you need: https://twigfiddle.com/hjyslr

Comment: Thanks... I just find it weird that they would require you apply raw to the final result, not a specific part of the result... I mean what if VendorData is normally not expected to have any html in it and I dont want "raw" in that case?

Comment: It's not weird. `filter's` just have a higher [precendence](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#expressions)

Comment: Hi there @SublymeRick - I added another Twigfiddle to show how you might achieve what you need using an if statement in Twig.